# How to stop execution of all js on page yii2?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

Yii2. Example: (.../index.php)

```
 <?php echo Html::a('Add new',  ['/rode/prod', 'id'=>$model->id ], ['onClick' => '
                var modal = $(".modal");
                $.get("/rode/prod?id='.$model->id.'", function(data) {
                modal.html(data).modal("show");
                });
                return false;'
            ]);?>
  <?php echo Html::a('Add new',  ['/rode/lok', 'id'=>$model->id ], ['onClick' => '
                var modal = $(".modal");
                $.get("/rode/lok?id='.$model->id.'", function(data) {
                modal.html(data).modal("show");
                });
                return false;'
            ]);?>
```

And other...

When start to run a modal window on click button, all others run. How to do, to run only once, but not all ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `id` in modals to identify them instead of `class`.

With unique `id` like i.e. `newProd` for the first model it will be:

```
var modal = $("#newProd");
```

For this to work you have to set `id` in modal's div like:

```
<div id="newProd" ...>
```

Add unique `id` to every modal like that.